# Does there exist a measure-like function on the reals satisfying the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Letting $P(\Bbb{R})$ denote the power set of the reals, does there exist a function $m : P(\Bbb{R}) \to [0, \infty]$ satisfying:

1. For all $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ with $a < b$, $m([a, b]) = b - a$
2. For any two disjoint subsets $S, T$ of $\Bbb{R}$, we have $m(S) + m(T) = m(S \cup T)$

I know it is impossible if you add a third condition that the measure is invariant under translations. But does there exist a measuring function on the reals if you remove that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the space of all bounded functions $: 
\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the sup norm. Define $\phi: L^{1}(\mathbb R)\cap X\to \mathbb R$ by $\phi (f)=\int f$. By Hahn Banach Theorem this extends to a continuous linear functional $\Phi$ on $X$. Define $m(E)=\Phi (\chi_E)$.

Comment: Is that defined on nonmeasurable subsets?

Comment: @Jose27 I have edited.

Comment: In [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiDvrOV1s3wAhURCWMBHVTNBycQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fdownload%2Fpdf_1%2Feuclid.ijm%2F1256047367&usg=AOvVaw1kFb-r7Nk4N4xZJlaTWwvV) Wagon proves that a translation invariant finitely additive measure (which is like Lebesgue on intervals) exists on $\Bbb R^n$ for every $n$.

Comment: Also show that $m(E) \ge 0$ for all $E$.  And is $\phi$ continuous for the sup norm?